# Aurelia named router-view / viewPorts not working

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm unable to get a layout view to be properly filled with the view-ports I'm specifying in the route config. I have a route "styleguide" which should use the "sidebar" layout, filling the "sidebar" router-view with "sidebar.html" and the "content" router-view with "content.ts / html"

**app.ts**

```
export class App {
  configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {
    config.map([{ 
      route: "styleguide", 
      name: "styleguide", 
      layoutView: "layout/sidebar.html",
      viewPorts: {
        sidebar: { moduleId: "styleguide/sidebar.html" },
        content: { moduleId: "styleguide/index" },
      }
    }]);
  }
}
```

**app.html**

```
<template>
  <router-view layout-view="layout/default.html"></router-view>
</template>
```

**layout/default.html** (not used in this example)

```
<template>
    <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

**layout/sidebar.html**

```
<template>
    <router-view name="sidebar"></router-view>
    <router-view name="content"></router-view>
</template>
```

**styleguide/sidebar.html**

```
<template>
  SIDEBAR!!
</template>
```

**styleguide/index.ts**

```
export class Index { }
```

**styleguide/index.html**

```
<template>
  CONTENT
</template>
```

Issues:

- "There was no router-view found in the view for styleguide/sidebar.html." -- Although I have specified the router-view name, etc.
- I do have another route which does not specify a `layoutView`, and thus uses the default. This only works when I replace the `router-view` element in layout/default.html with `slot`. I tried to use slots in both layouts but the sidebar layout gives me the same error.

Comment: How can you close <router-view name="sidebar"> with different close tag </slot> ? I think slot have different open tag. Please check this document https://aurelia.io/docs/routing/configuration#layouts

Comment: That was a typo -- thanks.

Comment: Also I've read that document and others around it and I feel like this should be working according to what I've read.

Answer (score 0):

The error you got is because of your `app.html` doesn't support `viewPorts`. There is only one `<router-view/>` with the default name, so with your route configuration with 2 viewports, it failed with the above error.

Layout, according to the documentation, seems like a way to achieve slot like behavior for your routes, not a place to put `<router-view/>` to me, it seems.